# How to send dynamic url from DataProvider to PDF Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to Flutter. I have DataProvider which consists of Pdf data like it's Title, pdfURL and etc and I created a **ListView** on that **ListView** I have some items.

Whenever I click on any item it should open specified pdf url on **PDF VIEWER**. I want to pass that data dynamically to the **getFileFromUrl**; how should I pass that data.

This is my DataProvider class:

```
class DataProvider with ChangeNotifier{

  List<PdfBook> _pdfItems = [
    PdfBook(
      id: 'p1',
      title: 'PDF Bookmark Sample',
      pdfUrl: 'https://www.adobe.com/support/products/enterprise/knowledgecenter/media/c4611_sample_explain.pdf',
      avatar: 'T',
    ),
    PdfBook(
      id: 'p2',
      title: 'PDF 995',
      pdfUrl: 'http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf',
      avatar: 'T2',
    ),
  ];

  List<PdfBook> get pdfItems{
    return [..._pdfItems];
  }

  PdfBook findById(String id){
    return _pdfItems.firstWhere((item) => item.id == id);
  }

}
```

This is my PdfViewState:

```
class PdfItem extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PdfItemState createState() => _PdfItemState();
}

class _PdfItemState extends State<PdfItem> {
  String assetPDFPath = "";
  String urlPDFPath = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    getFileFromAsset("assets/mypdf.pdf").then((f) {
      setState(() {
        assetPDFPath = f.path;
        print(assetPDFPath);
      });
    });

    getFileFromUrl("http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf").then((f) {
      setState(() {
        urlPDFPath = f.path;
        print(urlPDFPath);
      });
    });
  }

  Future<File> getFileFromAsset(String asset) async {
    try {
      var data = await rootBundle.load(asset);
      var bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List();
      var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      File file = File("${dir.path}/mypdf.pdf");

      File assetFile = await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
      return assetFile;
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception("Error opening asset file");
    }
  }

  Future<File> getFileFromUrl(String url) async {
    try {
      var data = await http.get(url);
      var bytes = data.bodyBytes;
      var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      File file = File("${dir.path}/mypdfonline.pdf");

      File urlFile = await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
      return urlFile;
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception("Error opening url file");
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final pdf = Provider.of<PdfBook>(context, listen: false);
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(pdf.title),
      onTap: () {
        if (urlPDFPath != null) {
          Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => 
                    PdfViewPage(path: urlPDFPath)));
        }
      }, 
      leading: CircleAvatar(
        child: Text(pdf.avatar),
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
      ),
      trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_right),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my ListView Class:

```
class PdfListView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final pdfData = Provider.of<DataProvider>(context);
    final pdf = pdfData.pdfItems;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("PDF Books"),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: pdf.length,
        itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: pdf[i],
          child: PdfItem(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```